# upgrading separate iPhone and iPad apps to a single universal binary

Tags: app-store, universal-binary, submission

I have two separate iPhone and iPad apps that I have now turned into a universal binary. I think I've done the hard part, but now I'm kinda stumped on how to submit that universal binary through iTunes connect in a way that users of the existing apps are prompted to upgrade. I know I could just submit this as an entirely new app and then pull the old stand-alone apps down, but I would lose the continuity of reports, reviews, and the prompting of the current users  to upgrade....

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, both your iPhone and iPad apps as have separate bundle identifiers on iTunes Connect. To be able to make users upgrade, and to keep your reviews and everything - you need to have a single bundle identifier.

What I can think of is - remove one of the apps and update the other one to the universal binary.